# Giving consent to cookies using rvest

Tags: r, cookies, rvest

Simple question, which I surprisingly couldn't find any answer to on SO: how can you give consent for cookies on websites.

I run code like:

```
require(rvest)
finances <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/financials?p=MSFT&_guc_consent_skip=1608408673"
finances <- read_html(finances)
finances <- html_table(finances,header = TRUE)
```

This give a empty data.frame, and I suspect it is because the websites asks for consent for tracking cookies. How does one give consent to such cookies using rvest?

Comment: Chances are this web page dynamically generates the page with JavaScript thus rvest isn’t working

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018915/div-class-scraping/64019146#64019146) that I've answered, I'll give you the code to get the data from the table:

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)
pg <- read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/financials?p=MSFT&_guc_consent_skip=1608408673")
js <- pg %>% html_node(xpath = "//script[contains(., 'root.App.main')]") %>% html_text()
ct <- new_context()
ct$eval(js)
data <- ct$get("App")
incomeStatementHistory <- data$main$context$dispatcher$stores$QuoteSummaryStore$incomeStatementHistory
incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly <- data$main$context$dispatcher$stores$QuoteSummaryStore$incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly
```