# Pulling Quarterly Stock Data from Yahoo using VBA - 2020 Updated

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

So I've been able to write a script that is able to pull stock fundamental data from Excel. Yay. I know the update has stumped many. Here is my current code. I am looking to interact with the webpage so that I can pull balance sheet and cashflow data as well. Also, I want to look at the data from a quarterly perspective and not annual. For ease of reference: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL

This will require me to press a button on the screen; however, I am not sure how to go about doing this.

```
Sub importData()    
For Each Chart In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
    Chart.Delete
Next


Dim dashboardSheet  As Worksheet
Dim dataSheet       As Worksheet
Dim market          As String
Dim startDate       As String
Dim endDate         As String
Dim frequencyCode   As String  ' Time Period

Dim dataURL         As String   'URL for Historical Data
Dim dataURL2        As String   'URL for Balance Sheet
Dim i               As Long    ' Counter for Existing Connections



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set dashboardSheet = cnDash
Set dataSheet = cnData





market = dashboardSheet.Range("C2").Value
startDate = dashboardSheet.Range("A3").Value
endDate = dashboardSheet.Range("A4").Value
frequencyCode = dashboardSheet.Range("C6").Value


dataURL = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" + market + "?period1=" + startDate + "&period2=" + endDate + "&interval=" + frequencyCode + "&events=history"

'   Clear the existing connections

For i = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count To 1 Step -1
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Delete
Next
'   Clear the Data
dataSheet.Cells.Delete

If dashboardSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then ' Delete sheet if it exists
    dashboardSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    dashboardSheet.Paste
Else
    dashboardSheet.Paste
End If



'   Pull data from Yahoo for Historical Graph '

dataSheet.Activate
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & dataURL, _
                                                  Destination:=dataSheet.Range("A1"))
    .Name = "import"
    .FieldNames = True ' field names in source data appear as column headers
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 1252
    .TextFileStartRow = 1               ' Start data from row 2 to exclude headings
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
    
    

'Pull data from Yahoo for Fundamentals '

Dim http As Object, s As String
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
With http
    .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + market + "/financials?p=", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send
    s = .responseText
End With




Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, re As Object, matches As Object

Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set html2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Set element = html.getElementsByClassName("Fz(s) Fw(500) D(ib) H(18px) C($primaryColor):h C($linkColor)")
element.Click




html.body.innerHTML = s

Dim headers(), rows As Object

headers = Array("Breakdown", "TTM")
Set rows = html.querySelectorAll(".fi-row")

With re
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"
    Set matches = .Execute(s)
End With

Dim results(), match As Object, r As Long, c As Long, startHeaderCount As Long
startHeaderCount = UBound(headers)
ReDim Preserve headers(0 To matches.Count + startHeaderCount)

c = 1
For Each match In matches
    headers(startHeaderCount + c) = match
    c = c + 1
Next

Dim row As Object
ReDim results(1 To rows.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

For r = 0 To rows.Length - 1
    html2.body.innerHTML = rows.Item(r).outerHTML
    Set row = html2.querySelectorAll("[title],[data-test=fin-col]")
    
    For c = 0 To row.Length - 1
        results(r + 1, c + 1) = row.Item(c).innerText
    Next c
Next

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")

With ws
    .Cells(1, 10).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    .Cells(2, 10).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    
Columns("K:K").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("L:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("M:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("O:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
End With
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call HistoricalGraph(dataSheet, dashboardSheet, market)

End Sub
```

Comment: "I am not sure how to go about doing this" with 3 pages of code is not a good question for SO. Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to scrape the exact page in R: [Giving consent to cookies using rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65374044/giving-consent-to-cookies-using-rvest/65380059#65380059)

To scrape this page, you need to run JS code. To do that in VBA, I think this is a good reference: https://ramblings.mcpher.com/get-started-snippets/step-by-step-guides/how-to-add-flightpaths-on-a-map/how-to-use-javascript-from-vba/